# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type - in a kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm playing around with a kernel module to learn the interface, so I want to print the processes in the Red Black tree of the CFS scheduler. So I want to access it via `current->se.cfs_rq->tasks_timeline` but this gave me a `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` on this line. I tried smiplifying it by accessing `(current->se.cfs_rq)->nr_running` but got the same error.

- I can define a `struct rb_node * node` and a `struct rb_root * root` so this is not the problem.

The whole code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/rbtree.h>
#include <linux/rbtree_augmented.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


int init_module(void)
{
    printk("%d\n", (current->se.cfs_rq)->nr_running);
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world proc.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "incomplete type" is an array type with an unspecified number of elements or a `struct` or `union` type with unspecified members.  You can declare and use a pointer to an incomplete type (typically of the `struct` or `union` flavor) but you cannot dereference it because the compiler doesn't know any details of the object pointed to.  This feature is essential where forward declaration of `struct` and `union` types is needed, but it is also useful for implementing abstract and opaque types.

If `struct rb_node` is the incomplete type in question, then you will need to complete it if you want to be able to do more than declare and pass around pointers to instances.  That means providing a declaration of `struct rb_node` that specifies its members.  Perhaps that's available from another header file.  If not, then that's a sign that you're not meant to be poking into the details of these things outside the code that's creating and consuming them (as distinguished from code that handles pointers to them).

Comment: Actually the incomplete type is the `cfs_rq` which points to the `rb_root`. Anyway, I do want to poke it, so what can I do?

Comment: OK, I copy-pasted the definition of the struct into my module and it works. Seems like bad code, but works :)